# How would you approach TDD-ing a spring web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tdd

I'm looking for advice on how would someone approach creating a spring web application (with hibernate) in a pure TDD fashion. Meaning that you shouldn't write production code without having a failing unit test for it first.

Would you be unit testing the creation of your application context? If yes how would you go about doing that?

Would it be easier to TDD a spring app when using java configuration instead of xml or annotation based configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you write a test that needs a Spring `ApplicationContext` and a database, then this is an integration test, not a unit test. The general rules for unit tests are:

- They test one thing (i.e. method calls to other classes / beans are frowned upon)
- They have a lean setup (i.e. no loading of test data into a database, no transactions, no huge app context)

Integration tests, on the other hand:

- Are slow (create database connection, loading test data into database, big setup step to wire many beans, configure spring, ...)
- Brittle (because of the many dependencies)
- If they fail, you only know that it's somewhere in the 500'000 lines of code that were executed.

So for TDD, you try to build beans which you can create without Spring. Write them in such a way that you don't have to start Hibernate or a database. The main reason here is that TDD needs to run the unit tests hundreds of times each day. If they run longer than 10 seconds, you will eventually feel like you're wasting your time waiting for the tests to finish.

The next question is usually how you can test anything useful this way. Well, think of it this way: Hibernate works. It already has many unit tests. Testing hibernate is a waste of time. So you should create an layer in your application which completely hides Hibernate from the code.

Instead of wiring a `FooDao`, wire an `IFooDao` that has a `byId()` method and returns a POJO. In unit tests, you can create a mock implementation that returns a single instance.

When you want to know whether the real `FooDao` works, write integration tests for that which call `byId()` a few times.

But avoid the "get object from DAO, process object, save object with DAO again". These are three distinct tests (two IT, one UT).

Comment: So, you suggest for example to start with a test which is testing a, lets say, controller which calls some other service for example, mock that other service, then write a new test to test that service and so on until you achieved your goal?

Comment: Yes. One of the most important core values of TDD is "small steps". When a test executes more than 100 lines of code, that's hardly ever a "small step".